# Undefined variable error

Tags: php

Hi I'm Denis and I'm new to php. My dad is a PHP developer but I want to do this on my own. I'm 11 years old now!!! :)

I made an installer for my php thing and I get this error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: config in \path\to\core.php on line 20
```

It's this part that is failing:

```
$system['home_url'] = "".$config['home']['url']."";
```

But how can it fail if I included the config file before and this variable is not undefined!

I did: `require('config.php');`

The config.php file code is:

```
$config['home']['url'] = "http://localhost/";
```

Am I using the variables right? I searched all the internet and I only found solutions using `global` but I don't really know how it works..

Bye!!! and thanks:)))

EDIT--
Core.PHP

```
<?PHP
/*=======================================================================
| #######################################################################
| This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
| it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
| the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
| (at your option) any later version.
| #######################################################################
| This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
| but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
| MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
| GNU General Public License for more details.
\======================================================================*/
require('config.php');

$system['home_url'] = "".$config['home']['url']."";
$system['updates_enabled'] = "".$config['updates']['enabled'].""; 
$system['update_url'] = "".$config['update']['url']."";
$system['language'] = $config['language'];
$system['favicon'] = "".$config['favicon'].""; 
$system['maintenance_status'] = "".$config['maintenance']['status'].""; 
$system['version'] = "".$config['version'].""; 
$system['master_user'] = "".$config['master']['user']."";
$system['master_password'] = "".$config['master']['password']."";
$system['config_path'] = "config.php";

/*====================================================================*/

$site['name'] = "".$config['site']['name']."";
$site['desc'] = "".$config['site']['desc'].""; 

/*====================================================================*/

$cloud_panel['reload_time'] = "".$config['reload']['time']."";

/*====================================================================*/

require "".$system['home_url']."lang/lang_".$system['language'].".php";

/*====================================================================*/

$template['id'] = "".$config['template']['id']."";
$template['webgallery_type'] = "".$config['webgallery']['type']."";
$template['webgallery_url'] = "".$config['webgallery']['url'].""; 

/*====================================================================*/

if(isset($_GET['help'])) { header('Location: '.$system['home_url'].'help.php'); }

/*====================================================================*/

if ($template['webgallery_type'] == 1) { $template['my_webgallery'] = "".$system['home_url']."cdn/web-gallery"; } else { $template['my_webgallery'] = $template['webgallery_url']; }

/*====================================================================*/

?>
```

Config.PHP

```
<?PHP
/*=======================================================================
| #######################################################################
| This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
| it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
| the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
| (at your option) any later version.
| #######################################################################
| This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
| but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
| MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
| GNU General Public License for more details.
\======================================================================*/

$config['site']['name'] = "heya";
$config['site']['desc'] = "heya";
$config['home']['url'] = "http://localhost/";
$config['updates']['enabled'] = "1";
$config['update']['url'] = "http://localhost/update";
$config['language'] = "es";
$config['favicon'] = "favicon.ico";
$config['maintenance']['status'] = "1";
$config['reload']['time'] = "10";
$config['version'] = "1.3.4";
$config['master']['user'] = "heya";
$config['master']['password'] = "heya";
$config['template']['id'] = "9";
$config['webgallery']['type'] = "1";
$config['webgallery']['url'] = "heya";

?>
```

Comment: is it an array? because you have a multidmensional array here

Comment: Do you sure that your script file at the same directory with config.php?

Comment: Scoping issues? Please show your complete code (as much as is relevant at least). Also: `"".$var.""` is pointless, you're concatenating an empty string to a variable to an empty string. Just do `$var`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments I'll post it right now and I'll follow your advice deceze

Comment: And yes it is in the same directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check variable before use lik `isset($config['home']['url'])` you can also use `!empty($config['home']['url'])`

Comment: I'd think the correct solution is to structure the code so the variable is accessible. Suppressing the error is not the solution, it just hides the symptom that tries to point out the error!